# Compress entire disk with 7-Zip

Tags: permissions, 7-zip

I want to create a ZIP file with the contents of a NTFS formatted external hard drive. I do not have permissions for many of the files on the drive. I do not want to give myself permissions on the drive or modify the existing permissions in any way.

The only way I've found of copying data without changing the permissions is to use robocopy with the /B option which uses SeBackupPrivilege.

Is there any way of using 7-Zip in a similar way?

Comment: Is using Linux an option?

Comment: What’s the purpose here? To create a backup that can restore the disk to the backed up state? A 7-Zip archive may not be suitable for that by itself.

Comment: Linux was my fallback strategy, unfortunately my most powerful computer only runs Windows which would make compression a lot faster. I do not plan on restoring the archive. I just want all the files accessible in a format that can be opened on any platform.

Comment: I think dumping it to a VHD(X) kinda suits you need, except most likely you can't compress on the fly.

Comment: 7-Zip is not for doing full-disk backup. Why not use a real backup utility?

Comment: My main reason for using ZIP is that essentially every platform can open it without 3rd party tools. I don't care about a bootable backup or anything, I just want to be able to access individual files. I think I might go with the VHDX method as it at least plays nicely with Windows.

Comment: You can boot eg. Ubuntu off a flash drive for this job. VHDX would be a good idea except it will preserve permissions, which technically speaking fits your needs as described, but it sounds like not preserving them would be more practical.